# List in a list in specified position Python

Tags: python, list

given a list `A = ['1', '2', '7','8']` and `B = ['3','4','5','6']`

I know I can do: `A.insert(2, B)` and I will get `A = ['1', '2', ['3','4','5','6'],'7','8']` which is not what I'm after.

I want something like this: `A = ['1', '2', '3','4','5','6','7','8']`. How can this be done in Python?

Comment: Use `A[2:2] = B` to extend `A` at a given index, see the duplicate.

Comment: @Wright it's not going to be sorted like that... I just gave an easy-reproducible example

Comment: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist] or list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l)) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: @Mixalis Not exactly sure what you mean, did you try it even and print C?